# DynamoDB Expected condition

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

What will happen if I create a PutItem request like this:

```
  {
    "Expected": 
        {
            "testAttribute" :
                {
                    "Exists": "false",
                }
        },
    "Item": 
        {
            "testAttribute" :
                {
                    "S": "testValue"
                }
        },
    "TableName": "TableName"
}
```

where "testAttribute" is not part of the primary key.

Will DynamoDB scan the table to see if there is an item with attribute "testAttribute" == "testValue" ?
If not, how will DynamoDB determine the presence of a "testAttribute" == "testValue" ?
I can't find anything in the docs describing how this works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [documentation of the `PutItem` action](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_PutItem.html), you are not allowed to issue that request. It says:

> Item: A map of attribute name/value pairs, one for each attribute. **Only the primary key attributes are required**; you can optionally provide other attribute name-value pairs for the item.

(emphasis mine)

You must provide a value for each attribute of the primary key whenever you use `PutItem`.

This way, as you will surely agree, it is very simple and fast for DynamoDB to check the condition you defined on the `Expected` clause: no scan is needed, it just has to look at the single item that *could* match the request. Otherwise, as you noted, DynamoDB would need to perform a full table scan (and it would possibly be very slow, and they would certainly charge you for that) or it would need to maintain a consistent index of every single item in a table, and they would charge you for the SSD space used to store it!

Also, note that the meaning of the *expected*  clause is a little bit different than what you described in the question. Supposing you fix your request and add all the primary key attributes, the request would mean:

> "If the item identified by this primary key does not exist, create it; if it does exist and does not contain an attribute named *testAttribute*, replace the item with the one whose attributes are described in this request; if the item does exist and does contain an attribute named *testAttribute*, do nothing".

Your description says that DynamoDB would check if the value of *testAttribute* is *testValue*, but it is not what happens when you use the `Expected/Exists` clause. To achieve the effect you described, you need to use the `Expected/Value` clause, and then you specify the value you are expecting in that clause -- the value specified for the attribute in the `Item` property of the request is just used to define the new value of the attribute, if an update (or insert) is to occur.